# Azure PUT BlockList returns 400 (Block ID is invalid. Block ID must be base64 encoded.)

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I have what seems to be a pretty simple test of uploading a large file to Azure Blob storage.

The response I get is 400:
400 (Block ID is invalid. Block ID must be base64 encoded.)

The URL I am uploading to is: https://xxxx.blob.core.windows.net/tmp/af620cd8-.....&comp=blocklist

with the body:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<BlockList>
<Latest>BLOCK0</Latest>
<Latest>BLOCK1</Latest>
</BlockList>
```

This comes after a couple of successful block uploads:
https://xxxx.blob.core.windows.net/tmp/af620cd8-02e0-fee2....&blockid=BLOCK0
etc.

It doesn't seem like anything here requires Base64 encoding and the block IDs are of the same exact size (something mentioned in another post).  Is there anything else I could try here?

The complete code is here:
https://github.com/mikebz/azureupload
and the specific front end file is here:
https://github.com/mikebz/azureupload/blob/master/formfileupload/templates/chunked.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The block ids must be base64 encoded and because you're not doing so, you're getting this error.

From [`Put Block`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd135726.aspx) REST API documentaion:

> blockid:  Required. **A valid Base64 string value that identifies the
>   block**. Prior to encoding, the string must be less than or equal to 64
>   bytes in size. For a given blob, the length of the value specified for
>   the blockid parameter must be the same size for each block. Note that
>   the Base64 string must be URL-encoded.